# Expectation of Reciprocal of Sum of i.i.ds

Tags: probability, expected-value

$X_i$s are real continous *i.i.d*s. I am trying to prove the conjecture

$$
E[\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}] = E[\frac{1}{nX_i}]
$$

I can't seem to be getting anywhere. Prove or disprove.

Comment: You can't seem to be getting anywhere, because this is false.

Comment: @adityadua write that down as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic mean is greater than or equal to the harmonic mean.

$${1 \over n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq {n \over \sum_{i=1}^n {1 \over X_i}}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n {1 \over X_i} \geq {n^2 \over \sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$$
$$n \mathbb{E} \left[ {1 \over X_1} \right] \geq n^2 \mathbb{E}\left[ {1 \over \sum_{i=1}^n X_i} \right] $$
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ {1 \over \sum_{i=1}^n X_i} \right] \leq {1 \over n}\mathbb{E} \left[ {1 \over X_1} \right]$$

Comment: This is not the RHS...

Comment: @user2268997 Better?

Comment: Sure. All you need now is to (formally) rule-out the equal in the less-than-or-equal.

Comment: There is at least one degenrate case ($X_i = const$) where the equality holds. Not sure how to prove that it is the only case.

Comment: I know. An alternative way would be to plug in some distribution for Xi and show that the equality does not hold for it.